# Loading part of file from server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have a large text file on server (21 GB). I would like to read part of it, from byte A to byte B.

Is it currently possible to do it with XmlHttpRequest, FileReader or Blobs, or any other interface? Without any special software on the server?

---

Actually, I just want to process the whole file locally. Entire file will not fit into my RAM (can't load it with single XMLHttpRequest). FileReader can read specific bytes of local file, but I would have to choose it manually into < INPUT >, each time I run the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can send a [`Range` header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.35) in your request (with XHR). If the server supports partial requests, then it can give you the bytes you ask for.

```
xhrInstance.setRequestHeader("Range", "bytes=500-999");
```

Note that you should expect a `206 Partial Content` response instead of a `200 OK` response.

Comment: And the server should respond with `Content-Length: 500` and `Content-Range: bytes 500-999/12345` where the number after the `/` is the total content-length. If you request a range above that number then the server will respond with a [416 Requested Range Not Satisfiable](http://httpstatus.es/416).